# RStudio keyboard shortcuts of Command+Enter and Option+Enter cannot work

Tags: r, version, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio, osx-yosemite

My RStudio keyboard shortcuts of Command+Enter and Option+Enter cannot work, after upgrading RStudio Version 1.0.136 on my Mac BookPro notebook. Any one can help me? Many thanks.

Best,

Gary

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rebind them to something different as a semi-solution. However, why the shortcuts don't work I couldn't tell you.

Go to `Tools -> Modify keyboard shortcuts` and in the search field type `run`. You will see the `Run current line or selection` and the bindings behind it. If they are empty then we have an immediate answer to your problem. If not, you can bind it to something different.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I bind it to Cmd + 7 (the figure below), but it still doesn't work. Could you help me again?
http://68.181.92.180/~Gary/temporal/RStudio_fig1.png

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on. It isn't due to the newer version. You're file extension is `.txt`. For RStudio to execute code it has to be an `.R` file. I'd recommend rebinding your `Run current line or selection` to the default again and then either change the extension of all your files to `.R` or create a new file in RStudio and save it as an `.R` file. Then everything should be fine.

Comment: You are right, and thank you so much. After I use an .R file, the keyboard shortcuts work again. However, I don't understand that I always use .txt files, and why the keyboard shortcuts work before?